# Convert game position to lat lng in rotated map

Tags: javascript, math, geolocation

I have math problem I can't wrap my head around and I feel stupid about it.

I have game bounds defined like this.

```
const GAME_BOUNDS = {
    x: {
        min: -3200,
        max: 4800
    },
    y: {
        min: -4000,
        max: 6000
    }
}
```

I have position ex. `const POS = {x: 100, y: -500}`. I would like to convert the position to correct lat/lng in my bounds. Where lng 180 is `x: 4800`. However the trick is, the map is rotated and I can't find the correct rotation i need to apply to get my correct lng/lat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a nifty function that maps a value x from one range xMin..xMax to another range yMin..yMax:

```
function remap(x, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax) {
    return yMin + (yMax - yMin)*(x - xMin)/(xMax - xMin);
}
```

Now say you want to map  x value from the -3200..4800 range to -180..180 and store it as the variable `lng`, and map y value from the -4000..6000 range to -90..90 and store it as `lat`:

```
let lng = remap(x, -3200, 4800, -180, 180);
let lat = remap(y, -4000, 6000, -90, 90);
```

Comment: I was doing something similiar, but my main problem is rotating the values to map the correct position on the map. I can get the lng / lat from my code which needs to be rotated by some value to match correct values on my map. If it helps I know where the values should be on the map so it would be easier to calculate the needed rotation.

Comment: Can you give more details about this rotation?

Comment: I have coordinates, converting them with your function gives me correct lng which is around -11.93159. However the latitude is wrong. It's around -42.76 with ur function while in reality it should be around -32.2071. I guess i need to apply some kind of rotation to the latitude. 

@Edit Also I know my bound are correct if that helps.

Comment: Can you tell more about the rotation you need to apply?

Comment: What do you exactly need to know? I don't know what informations you need because I myself have no clue what rotation I need to apply. If it helps you, I want to convert custom tile map to kibana.

Comment: Perhaps a picture, diagram or a screenshot, would help. For a rotation you need to define the angle of rotation and a point around which to rotate. For a general affine transformation you need to define mappings for three points. If it's a 3d rotation with a perspective mapping, it gets more complicated